# Using Ninject to inject IJob from external assembly into Quartz.net scheduler

Tags: c#, ninject, quartz.net, plugin-architecture, external-assemblies

I'm trying to create an application that can load external assemblies using Ninject and run them on a schedule using Quartz.net.

I have successfully implemented Quartz.net to be injected itself and run jobs based off classes implemented with IJob, from within the same assembly. This works well.

I would like to take it one step further and create a plugin architecture.

I have created a generic interface that all plugins will use, IPlugin, this interface also implements IJob. This is complied and referenced in the main application and each plugin implements it.

```
using Quartz;

namespace PluginFramework
{
    public interface IPlugin : IJob
    { }
}
```

Then I have a test plugin that implements IPlugin. Very straightforward, it just outputs a timestamp in green.

```
using System;
using PluginFramework;
using Quartz;

namespace TestPlugin
{
    public class Plugin : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Start();
        }

        private void Start()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - PLUGIN 1");
        }
    }
}
```

Before I added the Quartz.net framework, I would load and execute the plugin like so. The plugin would load, run once and the application would end, as expected.

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();

var assemblies = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\Plugins\", "*.dll");

foreach (var assembley in assemblies)
{
    kernel.Load(assembley);
}

var plugins = kernel.GetAll<IPlugin>();

foreach (var plugin in plugins)
{
    plugin.Execute();
}
```

Now I need the plugin to run on a schedule, but it *must* still be loaded via Ninject and the main application should remain agnostic to the type, it should just know it's an IJob and be able to run it on a schedule defined in some configuration. This is the bit I am having trouble with.

I have my NinjectJobFactory

```
public class NinjectJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

    public NinjectJobFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        Kernel = kernel;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle)
    {
        return (IJob)Kernel.Get(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (IJob) Kernel.Get(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {

    }
}
```

My factory provider and scheduler provider.

```
public class QuartzSchedulerFactoryProvider : Provider<ISchedulerFactory>
{
    protected override ISchedulerFactory CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var properties = new NameValueCollection();
        var section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("quartz");

        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = section["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"];
        properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = section["quartz.threadPool.type"];
        properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = section["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"];
        properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = section["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"];
        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = section["quartz.jobStore.type"];
        properties["quartz.plugin.xml.type"] = section["quartz.plugin.xml.type"];
        properties["quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames"] = section["quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames"];

        return new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
    }
}
```

```
public class QuartzSchedulerProvider : Provider<IScheduler>
{
    private readonly IJobFactory _jobFactory;
    private readonly IEnumerable<ISchedulerListener> _listeners;
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;

    public QuartzSchedulerProvider(
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory,
        IJobFactory jobFactory,
        IEnumerable<ISchedulerListener> listeners)
    {
        _jobFactory = jobFactory;
        _listeners = listeners;
        _schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
    }

    protected override IScheduler CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var scheduler = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.JobFactory = _jobFactory;

        foreach (var listener in _listeners)
        {
            scheduler.ListenerManager.AddSchedulerListener(listener);
        }

        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

and some configuration in an external XML file.

```
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>Plugin1</name>
        <group>Plugins</group>
        <description></description>
        <job-type>TestPlugin.Plugin, TestPlugin</job-type>
        <durable>true</durable>
        <recover>false</recover>
    </job>

    <trigger>
        <simple>
            <name>Plugin1</name>
            <group>Plugins</group>
            <job-name>Plugin1</job-name>
            <job-group>Plugins</job-group>
            <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
            <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
            <repeat-interval>1000</repeat-interval>
        </simple>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

Basically I'm not sure how to do it. I've tried a few things based on things I've found on Google/here, but nothing really helped. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to use dynamic module loading with Ninject [Look at bottom of the page](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) and set your module (ninject module) in these custom plugin assemblies to setup your implementations it should automatically do what you want.